# Adding a ReadOnly property to MaterialSingleLineTextField

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, controls

How to add a ReadOnly property to this control?

The control doesn't have a ReadOnly property.
I'm a beginner in C# and all I can think for now is this:

```
public class MaterialSingleLineTextFieldRO : MaterialSingleLineTextField
{
    public bool ReadOnly { ... };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it like any other property, but in setter, put desired behavior.

Since the `MaterialSingleLineTextFieldRO` uses a private `baseTextBox` field, you need to use reflection to find it and make it read only:

```
public class MyControl : MaterialSingleLineTextField
{
    bool readOnly;
    public bool ReadOnly
    {
        get { return readOnly; }
        set
        {
            readOnly = value;
            GetTextBoxControl().ReadOnly = value;
        }
    }
    private TextBox GetTextBoxControl()
    {
        var f = typeof(MaterialSingleLineTextField).GetField("baseTextBox",
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        return (TextBox)f.GetValue(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: The name of field has been changed to `baseTextBox`. I tested it with current edit and it works properly.

Comment: Just drop an instance of `MyControl` on your form, make it read only and run the program. You can see the result.

Comment: Sadly, it didn't appeared when I debugged. Yes, i drag and drop it. I don't know why but the there's a problem with the designer

Comment: Error in the designer: `'MyControl' does not exist in the type 'TestApp'`(my namespace) 

This is weird and I don't know why, I have the same namespace where I put your code

Comment: Although I did solve it before you edited your code by changing it in the source code, I want to try your code so I can accept it.

Comment: Oh wait, it worked! The error was this, `TestApp.MyControl myControl1` needed to change into this: `MyControl myControl1`

Answer (score 0):

Reza's solution solved my problem.

I have another solution by adding the code in the main source code (`MaterialSkin.dll`)

[image]